# Conversion of Gdk Events in Mono

Tags: events, mono, gtk#, gdk

I'm trying to intercept events using `Gdk.Window.AddFilter(Gdk.FilterFunc)` in Mono.  So far, I have been able to hook up the filter function, but now I am trying to use the events in the filter function.

This is what I have in the filter function so far:

```
private Gdk.FilterReturn FilterFunction(IntPtr xEvent, Gdk.Event evnt)
{
    if (evnt.Type == Gdk.EventType.KeyPress)
    {
        Gdk.EventKey eventKey = (Gdk.EventKey)evnt; // fails here

        if (eventKey.Key == this.key && eventKey.State == this.modifiers)
        {
            this.OnPressed(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    return Gdk.FilterReturn.Continue;
}
```

How can I convert the `Gdk.Event` to `Gdk.EventKey`?  I have tried casting it, but that doesn't seem to work.

**Edit:** Oops!  The problem was that I had accidentally added a semicolon to the `if` statement, making it an empty statement.  For some reason, the `Gdk.Event` does not correspond to the `XEvent`, so I am now pursuing a solution that uses the `XEvent` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try printing out the type so you can see what it really is? (it may not be `EventKey`)

Like:

```
Console.WriteLine (evnt.GetType ());
```

(or pause it in a debugger and examine it to see the type)